# NodeJs - Listen to keyboard input and answer to question in same program

Tags: node.js, keyboard-shortcuts

I need your advice.

I have a program where :
1/ I listen to keyboard input --> when user press "S" key, he opens a "Selling" function
2/ When this "Selling" function starts, it asks my users the quantity of tokens to sell, via a user prompt

But my problem is that I have troubles to make those 2 interactions work in //

Code for 1/

```
// Listen for keyboard input
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    console.log("Let's stop here");
    process.exit();
} else if (key.name === 's') {
    SellFunction();
}
```

Code for 2/

```
let sell_ratio = readlineSync.question(`How many %% of you tokens do you want to sell? (enter '50' for 50% / push Enter or 'y' to sell all): `);
```

Since the program is listening for keyboard input with 1/ , the characters do not appear on the terminal in 2/

I've read that I could use "process.stdin.resume()" to make the character appear on the screen again, but it's not ideal

--> what is the best way to "pause" listening keyboard input from 1/ temporarily while 2/ is running ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a readline interface whose input is not `process.stdin` but a "pass through" stream into which individual keystrokes are written by the `keypress` event handler.

Without the `input.write("\n")` statement, the "s" would become part of the answer that the user types in response to the "How many" question.

```js
var input = new stream.PassThrough();
var question;
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input,
  output: process.stdout
});
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on("keypress", (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === "c") {
    console.log("Let's stop here");
    process.exit();
  } else if (!question && key.name === "s") {
    input.write("\n");
    question = true;
    rl.question(..., function(answer) {
      question = false;
      console.log(answer);
    });
  } else
    input.write(str);
});
```